# Why is my calender in a different language?

Tags: unity, keyboard, 16.04, language-support, calendar

For some reason, my calendar is not being displayed in English.  Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Text Entry.

I'd guess that you see the language of the time zone location which you chose at installation. The installer 'guessed' that you prefer the regional formats of that location.

You can [change the regional formats setting](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html) if you like.